# Add An If in A Foreach Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I'm trying to add part of a `foreach loop` on a condition like this:

```
foreach ( $woocommerce as $key => $woop ) {

  $type = $woop['woo'];

  if ( class_exists( 'WooCommerce' )  {

    $woo = array(
      'posts_per_page' => 3,
      'post_type'      => 'product',

      )

  }
}
```

But I got an error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' for the  *if ( class_exists( 'WooCommerce' )  {*
```

Is there a way to add an if in a foreach loop ?

Comment: You're missing a close bracket `}` of `foreach`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just forgot to close your bracket on the conditional

Replace your line with this
`if ( class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ) {`

Comment: Just make sure you close both your if statement and your for loop. As Huy Nguyen said above, you've also forgotten a closing curly brace.